# How can I get the value of header parameter from NSerror?

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, afnetworking

I am new to objective C, I want to get useful information from NSError. I want to get the value of key "errorMessage" from the header parameters of the error message as send from the server. I am using AFNetworking. When I print out [error userInfo], it shows as follow:

```
{
   status code: 417, headers {\n    \"Content-Length\" = 0;\n    \"Content-Type\" = \"application/json\";\n    Date = \"Thu, 12 Feb 2015 08:37:08 GMT\";\n    Server = \"Apache-Coyote/1.1\";\n    errorCode = ORD012;\n    errorMessage = \"Couldn't found suitable client at this moment\";\n}
}";
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://blog.gregfiumara.com/archives/239 ?

Comment: Which version of AFNetworking are you using?

Comment: @DavidCaunt I am using 2.0, anyway I solved the problem. Thanks!